# Need help figuring out what I did wrong in my Gradient Descent code for Linear Regression with one variable

Tags: machine-learning, octave, linear-regression

I am enrolled in Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course. And there is an assignment, which I did complete of course... but the code I was using earlier wasn't working... and in the end I had to look for the right answer on Internet.

But anyways, from "wasn't working" I mean that it was working for that particular question, but thing is when they check my code then they have a different training set so my code should work with all types of training sets in order to be considered a right code. But the problem was that my code wasn't working with other training sets.

Now, to make it a bit more clear... all other training sets were supposed to have only one feature... that is we only needed to implement linear regression with one variable.

So I did everything right till the part where we have to calculate cost function. But when I had to compute the gradient descent, in that function I had to just write the code for the gradient descent steps.

So here's my code -

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters

% First Step
Prediction = X*theta;
A = (Prediction - y);

theta(1) = theta(1) - ((alpha * (1/m)) * sum(A' * X(:,1)));

% Second Step
Prediction = X*theta;
A = (Prediction - y);

theta(2) = theta(2) - ((alpha * (1/m)) * sum(A' * X(:,2)));



J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

Here is the code which is working, which I found on Internet... from one of the threads in Stack Overflow only -

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters

Prediction = X*theta;
A = (Prediction - y);

theta = theta - ((alpha * (1/m)) * (A' * X)');


J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

From what I can see from my code, that it should work properly... but dunno why it isn't working with other training sets? Because no matter how many training examples there are, it is always gonna be a column vector, or m*2 if we add x0. So I don't see how my code won't work?

Comment: I See similiar questions every third week. Have you read the previous and their answers?

Comment: Sorry I haven't searched enough threads. But I want to get a review of my code... so I don't think I can really find the answer from other threads I guess?